# How to solve more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing with some hook problem on my project. Here is the function to check user permission then should return true or false.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const CheckPermission = (module_key, permission_key) => {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => ({
    user: state.auth.user,
  }));

  const rolePermissions = user?.role?.role_permissions ?? [];

  const return_value = !!rolePermissions.find(
    (p_list) =>
      p_list.module?.key === module_key &&
      p_list.permission?.key === permission_key
  );

  return return_value;
};

export default CheckPermission;
```

Then i am using it on my sidebar component like

```
const renderMenu = (menu, key) => {
  if (!CheckPermission(menu.moduleKey, menu.permissionKey)) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Tooltip title={menu.name} placement="right" key={key}>
      <NavLink
        activeClassName={styles.active}
        exact
        className={styles.item}
        to={menu.path}
      >
        <span className={styles.iconBox}>{menu.icon}</span>
        <span className={styles.itemText}> {menu.name}</span>
      </NavLink>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default ({ collapse, onCollapse, isAdmin }) => {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => ({
    user: state.auth.user,
  }));

  return (
    <Layout.Sider
      theme="light"
      className={classnames(styles.sider, collapse ? styles.collapsed : "")}
      collapsible
      collapsed={collapse}
      onCollapse={onCollapse}
      width={collapse ? 64 : 264}
      onBreakpoint={() => {}}
      breakpoint="xl"
      style={{
        overflow: "auto",
        height: "100vh",
        position: "fixed",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        paddingTop: "50px",
      }}
    >
      <div className={styles.action}>
        {user && user.read_only
          ? menus.map((menu, i) => {
              if (menu.name === "Харилцагч") {
                return renderMenu(menu, i);
              } else {
                return (
                  menu &&
                  menu.children &&
                  // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
                  menu.children.map((submenu, j) => {
                    if (submenu.name === "QR данс") {
                      return (
                        <div key={i} className={styles.parentnav}>
                          {renderMenu(submenu, j)}
                        </div>
                      );
                    }
                  })
                );
              }
            })
          : menus.map((menu, i) => {
              if (menu.path) {
                return renderMenu(menu, i);
              } else {
                return (
                  <div key={i} className={styles.parentnav}>
                    {menu.name ? (
                      <div
                        className={`${styles.navlabel}  ${styles.partentText}`}
                      >
                        {menu.name}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                    {menu.children.map((submenu, j) => {
                      if (!submenu.path) return null;

                      if (isAdmin) {
                        return renderMenu(submenu, j);
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    })}
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
      </div>
    </Layout.Sider>
  );
};
```

But it throws "Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." how can i correctly use my checkPermission function in any other places.

I tried checkPermission function in loop through menu array then result is same.